# PHP Regex Get Text Between BBCode Tags

Tags: php, regex

I need help with the PHP code for the following:

Get the text between each occurrence the BBCode tags [code] and [/code] in a given string so I can then replace the spaces ' ' with the nbsp character.

Long story short, I can't use CSS or DOM to do this, I need to do this on the server.

#[code](.*?)[/code]# seems to only work if there are no breaks (or newlines) between the starting and ending tags.... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're searching for something like this

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/ism", $search, $match);
```

hover, I'd suggest you to use BBcode parsers instead

---

To replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`, simply use `preg_replace_callback`

```
<?php
$text = preg_replace_callback("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/ism", function($match) {
     return str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $match[1]);
}, $search);
```

Comment: This is too greedy. Needs to use (.*?) so that you get each instance of the code block.

Comment: This worked! However, how do I replace the spaces ' ' in everything it matched with &nbsp and return the whole modified string at the end? Thanks!

Comment: @Martin. How do I change this so that I can replace the spaces with &nbsp. Your pattern gives me an array of strings that contain the text between the code tags, but how do I then replace the spaces there and then return ALL of the original string with the now modified spaces?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it through a series of str_replace calls. Crappy programming that I'm not really proud of, but it'll work. Thanks for your help @Martin and jasonbar.

Comment: @Max sorry I haven't answered your question about spaces, I had some bad day and forgot how I've done it before. Callback! Here it is, I've edited my answer, so you can use less crappy code :)