# Regex in MySql - replace between Tags including Tags

Tags: php, mysql, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Regex Get Text Between BBCode Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640670/php-regex-get-text-between-bbcode-tags)

I have a text like:

> [lang_de]Content in German[/lang_de][lang_en]Content in English[/lang_en].

I want to replace all text between `[lang_en]` and `[/lang_en]` including the opening and closing language tag.

This is my current regex:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '" . addslashes(preg_replace("/[lang_en](.*)[\/lang_en]/", '', $row['post_content'])) . "' WHERE ID = " . $row['ID']
```

With this regex, I do not get a valid results. It also replaces in html tags and so on.

What would be the correct regex?

This is a text example:

```
[lang_de]
<!--more-->
<div class="s-desc">
<br/>
Länge: 3:50 min | Tempo: 125 bpm
<p>
Text<br/>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#">LoFi-Version zum Testeinsatz in Ihrem Projekt hier downloaden</a>.     (Rechstklick-->Ziel speichern unter...)<br/>
Die Nutzung dieser LoFi-Version ist ausschließlich für Testzwecke erlaubt!
</p>
</div>
[/lang_de]


[lang_en]<!--more-->
<div class="s-desc">
<br/>
Length: 3:50 min | Tempo: 125 bpm
<p>
Text<br/>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#">Download a lofi-version to test with your project here</a>. (right-click-->save target as...)<br/>
The usage of this lofi-version is permitted for testing purposes only!
</p>
</div>
[/lang_en]
```

The result shall look like this:

```
<!--more-->
<div class="s-desc">
<br/>
Länge: 3:50 min | Tempo: 125 bpm
<p>
Text<br/>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#">LoFi-Version zum Testeinsatz in Ihrem Projekt hier downloaden</a>.     (Rechstklick-->Ziel speichern unter...)<br/>
Die Nutzung dieser LoFi-Version ist ausschließlich für Testzwecke erlaubt!
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/\[lang_en](.*?)\[\/lang_en]/s", '', $text);
                            ^              ^
                          lazy             |
                                   '.' matches newlines as well
```

*Simple test [here](http://ideone.com/WGOfM).*

Comment: This does not work. This regex also replaces letters and other html Tags.

Comment: Test the code at http://ideone.com/WGOfM

Comment: "This regex also replaces letters" Don't you want it to replace letters?

Comment: I think he doesn't realize you escaped the square brackets

Comment: Sure. But also letters outisde these Tags get replaced.

Comment: That's because in regex, square brackets denote character classes. To assume literal meaning, they must be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Now it replaces everything, please have a look at my edit above.

Comment: @user998163 did you literally copy the solution in this answer? Cos I don't think you did.

Comment: @user998163 - there is just one answer (so far) listed. So be sure you copy the code/solution after it was updated...

Comment: @Ωmega I did. I took the updated version from your answer.

Comment: @user998163 - So then it HAS to work, as shown in example. There is nothing else we can help you with. Code is working and good. You have to have some other issues in your code.

Comment: Yep. I copied your code. You replaced $row['post_content'] width $text. I did not see that. $text was not defined, so nothung got inserted. Many Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Click here: http://ideone.com/WGOfM. That would be all from me.

Comment: @Ωmega It only works in 80% of the cases. I just posted an example, where it does not work: http://ideone.com/h8TSD

Comment: user998163 - well, for multiline you have to add `/s` to pattern, so `.` will match also `\n`. I have updated the answer. See also http://ideone.com/BHR8C for your example update.