# How is it possible to take values out of a text that are between two values and add them to an array?

Tags: php

Example:

example text/ string

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [TEST]consetetur[TEST] sadipscing elitr,
> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
> dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
> sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
> [TEST]consetetur[TEST] sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
> invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
> At vero eos et accusam et [TEST]justo[TEST] duo dolores et ea rebum.
> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
> dolor sit amet."

What I want (as result)

```
[
    0 => consetetur,
    1 => consetetur,
    2 => justo
];
```

Can anyone guide me on the right path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Regex Get Text Between BBCode Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640670/php-regex-get-text-between-bbcode-tags)

Comment: The following RegEx would do the job: `~\[TEST\](.+)\[TEST\]~gUs` (the `g` flag means you need to use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all)).

Comment: Thanks @AymDev that´s what I was looking for! It works with preg_match_all. I just changed the pattern to /\[TEST\](.*?)\[TEST\]/

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [TEST]consetetur[TEST] sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [TEST]consetetur[TEST] sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et [TEST]justo[TEST] duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
preg_match_all("/\[TEST](.+?)\[TEST]/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```